# lalasd.style is undefined

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguente error :

```
lalasd.style is undefined
```

Lo que quiero hacer es recorrer todas las clases con el nombre `sliders`, pero al momento de querer agregarle un estilo me sale eso que la variable no esta definida, pero yo ya la he definido.

*Nota*: cuanto cambio **queryselectorAll** , por **queryselector** sí funciona, pero solo selecciona el primer *div*, y yo quiero que seleccione *todos los div*, para poder hacer cambios.

Aqui dejo el codigo de js:

```
'use strict'

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  var lalasd = document.querySelectorAll('.sliders');

  console.log(lalasd);

  lalasd.style.transform = "scale(120%)";

  var contentPortada = document.querySelector('.content-portade');
  var right = document.querySelector('.right');
  var left = document.querySelector('.left');
  var moverPortada;

  contentPortada.scrollLeft = 1140;

  left.addEventListener('click', () => {
    contentPortada.scrollLeft += 300;
  });

  right.addEventListener('click', () => {
    contentPortada.scrollLeft -= 300;
  });

});
```

Comment: `querySelector` devuelve un objeto DOM con su estilo, sus atributos y todo... `querySelectorAll` devuelve un ARRAY. Obviamente, `[].style` no tiene mucho sentido. Si quieres usar ese selector, debes recorrer el resultado y aplicar las modificaciones que quieras a cada elemento.

Comment: y como lo hago lo hice con foreach , pero no se como capturar todo los div y como guardarlo en una variable para aplicarle los estilos

Comment: No te rayes. En un `for` usando `i` de `0` a `lalasd.length` (excluido) puedes usar `lalasld[i].style` y aplicar los estilos que quieras.

Comment: me darias un ejemplo ? en codigo , intente el lalasd[i].style.transform , pero me sale  i is not defined

Comment: ya pude mateo , lo que pasa esque puse lo que me dijiste , pero lo puse afuera del for , el lalasld[i].style , pero ahora que lo puse adentro del for, si ha funciona, debe ir adentro verdad del for el stylo ,para que funcione ?

Comment: Si, @MiguelAngel, tiene que ir dentro del for. El for lo que hace es ir cambiando el valor de `i` para que tú puedas acceder a cada elemento del array, pero esa variable `i` solo *"existe"* dentro del for.